# Indexing over composite types in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given the following, what can I expect of the resulting index?

```sql
CREATE TYPE instant AS (
    epoch_seconds timezonetz,
    nanos         integer
);

CREATE TABLE event AS (
    label      text,
    occurrence instant
);

CREATE INDEX idx_event_occurrence ON event (occurrence);
```

Will postgres automatically create a composite index over all the fields in `instant`?  Would this index then use the left field as the primary and the right as the secondary?  Would there be any reason to do the following instead?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_event_occurrence ON event (
    (occurrence).epoch_seconds,
    (occurrence).nanos
);
```

Comment: Just create those two indexes with different names and try selecting data with EXPLAIN ANALYZE. so you'll get an answer.